# Custom exported - File does not get "released" until I close blender

Tags: python

I have this custom exporter, that works fine.
The only problem is that the file seems to be blocked by Blender until I close Blender.

The exported file size is 0 bytes until I close blender and If I try to delete the file while blender is open, it tells me it's been used by another program.

This is the beginning and the end of the exporter (I see the last message "Exported successfully" in the console)

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "GAL Exporter",
    "author": "WAG",
    "version": (1,0,0),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "File > Export",
    "description":  "Export to Golden Age Level format",
    "category":"Import-Export",
}

class GAL_Exporter(bpy.types.Operator, ExportHelper):
    bl_idname = "export_mesh.gal"
    bl_label = "GAL Export"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    filename_ext    = ".gal";
    filter_glob     = StringProperty(default="*.gal", options={'HIDDEN'})
    
    # Export options
    apply_modifiers = BoolProperty(
        name="Apply Modifiers",
        description="Apply Modifiers to the exported mesh",
        default=True,
        )
        
    global_scale = FloatProperty(
        name="Scale",
        min=0.01, max=1000.0,
        default=1.0,
        )

 def execute(self, context): 
        global fw
        global mesh 
        global l_color_data
        global endianes
        global l_color_multipler
        
        filepath = self.filepath
        filepath = bpy.path.ensure_ext(filepath, self.filename_ext)
    
        file = open(filepath, "wb")
        fw = file.write

        #here I export all the data

        file.close            
        print ("Exported Succesfully")
        
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

What should I do for Blender to release the file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running functions in Python requires parentheses. Try `file.close()` maybe.

Else than that, the problem is likely to be located at line:

```
#here I export all the data
```

Comment: The parentheses, that was it. Thanks so much!

Comment: Can also use the safer `with open(path) as f:` that will automatically release the handle if something bad happens